# On Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> What is Schwarz inequality in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$? Give another proof of it in these cases.

Here is my attempt in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ both in $\mathbb R^2$. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is

$$\lvert\langle x,y \rangle \rvert \leq \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert.$$
Then our claim is

$$(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2 \leq (x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2).$$

Proof for this inequality: since $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2 \geq 0$, add
$(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2$ to both sides:
\begin{align*}
(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2 & ≤ (x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2+(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2 \\
& =(x_1y_2)^2+(x_2y_1)^2 -2(x_1y_2)(x_2y_1) \\
& \qquad +(x_1y_1)^2+(x_2y_2)^2+2(x_1y_1)(x_2y_2) \\
& =x_1^2(y_1^2+y_2^2) +x_2^2(y_1^2+y_2^2) \\
& =(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2),
\end{align*}
namely
$$(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2\leq (x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2).$$
This proves the claim.

My question is: is this answer complete to the given question? As there is a choice for $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$. If any step is missing please identify it.

Comment: I guess you should do a similar thing in the case of $\mathbb R^3$. The steps look good to me.

Comment: Note that I have modified the format of the entire question. Please, use MathJax next times. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine ! But:

you wrote:      $ \quad "$  our claim is

$$ (x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2 \leq (x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)."$$

It should read:

$$(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2 \leq (x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2).$$